# Best practices / tools for high performance IIS?

Tags: performance, iis, webserver, scalability

Recently I come across high performance web server nginx.

I would wonder, where does IIS stands as far as performance matters?

What are the tools/best practices to increase IIS 7 / 7.5 performance for a web application hosted on IIS.

Web Servers like Apache, nginx, or IIS plays an important role in performance and this would definitely help developers to understand how does it matters to choose correct web server for scalable web application.

Comment: Why this question is voted for close? I would like to know the reason what is wrong with this question, as there are many questions like this are already here with many votes? I would like to understand what makes few of the people angry here?

Comment: As per the FAQ: "only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site". If you have a particular performance issue with Apache/nginx vs. IIS, feel free to post your exact scenario and ask for advice. This question, however, isn't on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to do a meaningful benchmarks/comparison between Apache/Nginx and IIS, but if you're really concerned about ASP.NET/IIS performance, this is a good start: [Chapter 6 — Improving ASP.NET Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647787.aspx).

In practice, profiling your application/addressing the performance issues within application and properly using caching would likely result in much bigger performance gain as compared to simply tuning IIS.